# Jekyll `site.posts` appearing empty after incorporating custom domain with Github page

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am building a simple static site as my personal website with Jekyll. I am using GitHub pages for hosting it (https://username.github.io). Recently I am trying to incorporate my custom domain with it and facing a problem.

For example, I have a page titled `posts.html` whose content is like this:

```
---
layout: page
title: Posts
permalink: posts
---

Some Text

<ul>
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        <li> List item </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Previously everything was appearing as expected. But after incorporating custom domain no list item is appearing(even though everything is perfect when I run locally). I suppose `site.posts` is appearing empty. Any suggestion why is?

I have another page like following which loops through something other than `site.posts`. It is appearing perfect even after incorporating custom domain.

```
---
layout: page
title: Books I Have Read
permalink: read-books
---

Some text

<ul>
    {% for book in site.data.read-books %}
        <li>
            <a href={{book.goodreads}}> {{book.title}} </a>;
            {{book.author}} [{{book.date}}]
            {% if book.comment %}
                <br/>
                (Opinion: {{book.comment}})
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Format of my posts: `YYYY-MM-DD-title.md`

Name of posts directory: `_posts`

Local Jekyll version is: 3.7.0

`_config.yml` content:

```
Title: Md. Taufique Hussain
brieftitle: Taufique
baseUrl: ""
# Where things are
source:          .
destination:     ./_site
collections_dir: .
plugins_dir:     _plugins
layouts_dir:     _layouts
data_dir:        _data
includes_dir:    _includes
collections:
  posts:
    output:   true

# Handling Reading
safe:                 false
include:              [".htaccess"]
exclude:              ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "node_modules", "vendor/bundle/", "vendor/cache/", "vendor/gems/", "vendor/ruby/"]
keep_files:           [".git", ".svn"]
encoding:             "utf-8"
markdown_ext:         "markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md"
strict_front_matter: false

# Filtering Content
show_drafts: null
limit_posts: 0
future:      false
unpublished: false

# Plugins
whitelist: []
plugins:
    - jekyll-seo-tag

# Conversion
markdown:    kramdown
highlighter: rouge
lsi:         false
excerpt_separator: "\n\n"
incremental: false

# Serving
detach:  false
port:    4000
host:    127.0.0.1
baseurl: "" # does not include hostname
show_dir_listing: false

# Outputting
permalink:     date
paginate_path: /page:num
timezone:      null

quiet:    false
verbose:  false
defaults: []

liquid:
  error_mode: warn

# Markdown Processors
rdiscount:
  extensions: []

redcarpet:
  extensions: []

kramdown:
  auto_ids:       true
  entity_output:  as_char
  toc_levels:     1..6
  smart_quotes:   lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo
  input:          GFM
  hard_wrap:      false
  footnote_nr:    1
```

Comment: What does your browser's debugging console say..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is you want to locally test Jekyll in Github Pages configuration, your Gemfile must contain :

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'github-pages'
```

All plugins available on gh pages will be loaded, see [complete list here](https://pages.github.com/versions/).

This will allow you to reproduce gh pages error which comes from one of your config directive :

```
collections_dir: .
```

If you delete or comment this directive everything is back to normal.

Comment: Thank you. I copied the config from [Jekyll's default configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration) and edited to my preferences. Default may have been changed a bit now but I didn't touch the `collections_dir` part and it's still there. Can you please explain what was the matter with this directive?

Comment: This certainly a bug in the documentation.